# Json parsing nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Need help in parsing json file. I need to extract 'choices' from the file below.

```
{"questions":[
    {"question1": "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", "choices":       ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], "correctAnswer":0},
    {"question": "North West", "choices": ["What is the name of Kim Kardashian's baby?", "What is the opposite of south?"], "correctAnswer":0},
    {"question": "What's my favorite color?", "choices": ["Black", "Blue", "Magenta", "Red"], "correctAnswer":1},
    {"question": "What's the meaning of life?", "choices": ["Too live happily", "To give to the greater good"], "correctAnswer":1}
]}
```

nodejs script:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile(__dirname + "/lib/questions.json", "Utf-8", function(err, data){
jsoncontent = JSON.parse(data);
//console.log(jsoncontent);

for (var i = 0; i < jsoncontent.length; ++i) {
//code

}

});
```

How to extract?

Comment: define `extract` in terms of showing expected results. Also show the code you have used to try to solve this yourself. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to show your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
var choiceList;
for (var i = 0; i < jsoncontent["questions"].length; ++i) {
     //do what ever you want with choices
     choiceList = jsoncontent["questions"][i]["choices"];
     console.log(choiceList);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you i think. you can see here, it's giving you each row over entire loop

Answer (score 0):

```
const choices = jsoncontent.questions.map(q => q.choices);
```

That will give you an array with just the "choices" properties.

```
jsoncontent.questions.forEach(q => console.log(q));
```

That will print out "choices".

```js
const jsoncontent = {
  "questions":[
    {
      "question1": "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
      "choices": ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
      "correctAnswer":0
    },
    {
      "question": "North West", 
      "choices": ["What is the name of Kim Kardashian's baby?", "What is the opposite of south?"], 
      "correctAnswer":0
    },
    {
      "question": "What's my favorite color?", 
      "choices": ["Black", "Blue", "Magenta", "Red"], 
      "correctAnswer":1
    },
    {
      "question": "What's the meaning of life?", 
      "choices": ["Too live happily", "To give to the greater good"], 
      "correctAnswer":1
    }
]}

const choices = jsoncontent.questions.map(q => q.choices);
console.log(choices);

jsoncontent.questions.forEach(q => console.log(q));
```